# Please help with a Hypergeometric probability question

Tags: hypergeometric-function

Need help with this question, my textbook has the solution but I don't know how to get it.

15 coins in a bag.
Three 5 rand coins
Five 2 rand coins
Seven 1 rand coins

What is the prob that if I pull out 5 random coins, it equals 10 rand
The solution is 0.1752

I put all possible options that would give 10 rand over 15 choose 5, but unless I missed one which I'm pretty sure I haven't, I got the wrong answer of 0.441

Comment: @saulspatz I have tried but the solution is very long as it has all the possible combination sequences over the sample space so it would be difficult to post and type out

Comment: You only have to figure out what combinations add up to $10$ rands.  There are very few.

Comment: There are 8 that I worked out, but it comes to the wrong answer

Comment: @saulspatz just wanted to thank you for your help, completely forgot about the condition of only 5 coins being picked - feeling a little embarrassed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ${15\choose 5}=3003$ ways to pick $5$ coins.

The only ways for them to add up to $10$ rands are if you choose $5$ two-rand coins (one way) or $1$ five-rand coin, $1$ two-rand coin, and $3$ one-rand coins (${3\choose1}{5\choose1}{7\choose3}=525$ ways.)  So the probability is $${526\over3003}=0.17515817515817517...$$